# "The parameter href is required" error using Facebook Page Plugin

Tags: facebook

A user reported that the Page Plugin widget throws an error for him: "the parameter href is required".
So I dug a little deeper, and found that if I put the demo code (which can be found on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin/) in a codepen, it throws the same error, as you can see here: [image: here].

HTML:

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/page.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Ffacebook&tabs=timeline&width=340&height=500&small_header=true&adapt_container_width=true&hide_cover=false&show_facepile=true&appId" width="340" height="500" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe>
```

Here's the pen: https://codepen.io/binoculars88/pen/gOaYGBX .

On the docs page it does work, but that might be because of a different type of integration.

It is working properly on my end, so I find it very hard to debug. The user isn't using an ad blocker. Any tips?

Comment: Works absolutely fine for me as well, in that very codepen you have shown. No such error message visible anywhere, instead it renders the page plugin as expected.

Comment: _“The user isn't using an ad blocker.”_ - do they get a different result, when opening this in a private browser window, and with _all_ extensions disabled in that mode?

Comment: (If they are half-way technically competent, I’d ask them to check what HTML code their browser actually received, and for a screenshot of the iframe element in DOM inspector element view first of all.)